# issue with numberOfSectionsInTableView method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    NSLog(@"Test1");
     return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
     //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
     // Return the number of rows in the section.
      NSLog(@"No. of sections- %d",section);
      return [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count] ;//no. of rows
  }
```

In the above scenario, `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method is being called twice before tableView method is called. I can't understand why.

The other thing that confuses me is that when I returned `1` as number of sections in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method, why does it not reflect in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method? It rather logs it as `0`.

Doesn't the section parameter get updated since I set it as `1` previously? I mean at runtime the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method is called internally so obviously `section` parameter is supposed to hold some value.

Isn't that the case?

Comment: Number of sections count starts at 0, so if you declare you only have one section, its index will be zero. That's why you see section 0 in cellForRow

Answer (score 1):

Number of section is the count of sections in the TableView & the index of row & section starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Sections and rows in tableViews are just like arrays, they start with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this inspite of returning 1:-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    NSLog(@"Test1");
     return [yourArray count];
 }
```